# Nice query to get my friends

Tags: mysql

my table has this structure:

```
 User_ID | Followed_ID
```

Example row:

```
 33 | 36
```

Means that user 33 follows user 36.

If exists a record like

```
 36 | 33
```

then the two users are considered friends.
**What's the cleanest way to get all friends of(for example) user 36? Thanks.**

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: Then why did you tag with [sql-server]?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a simple join (assuming the `(user_id, follower_id)` combination has a unique constraint):

```
SELECT 
    f1.followed_id AS friend_id
FROM
    follow AS f1
  JOIN
    follow AS f2
      ON  f1.user_id = f2.followed_id
      AND f1.followed_id = f2.user_id
WHERE
    f1.user_id = 36 ;
```